# Python. How to call a function that expect ctypes array. Strand/Straus7

Tags: python, arrays, ctypes

I'm using python scripting for Strand/Straus7 importing his DLL.

I'm trying to call a function for set the units, called St7SetUnits, following the manual ([Img.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Pogu.png)) and watching the *.py* scripting of the DLL that I imported ([Img.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1gc3.png)). The function expected a *c_long* and a *ctypes.POINTER.(c_long)*, as specify in the script ([Img.3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqZNL.png))

Here the complete manual  strand7.com/downloads/Strand7%20R246%20API%20Manual%20TOC.pdf

and here the *.py* scripting https://www.dropbox.com/s/88plz2funjqy1vb/St7API.py?dl=0

As specify at the beginning of the manual I have to convert the list in ctypes array ([Img.4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8JWJ.png)).
The function I call is the same of the example, but I can't call it correctly.
I write

```
import St7API as SA
import ctypes 

SA.St7Init()

unitsArray = ctypes.c_int * SA.kLastUnit
units = unitsArray()
units[0] = 0
units[1] = 1
units[2] = 3
units[3] = 1
units[4] = 1
units[5] = 2
SA.St7SetUnits(1, units)
```

But returns error

```
expected c_long, got c_long_Array_6
```

If I try something else, for example an int from the array

```
SA.St7SetUnits(1, units[0])
```

the error change in

```
 expected LP_c_long, got int
```

I tried many solution, but no one works.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks a lot

Comment: If possible, it's better to (a) link to the actual manual rather than a screenshot of it, and (b) copy and paste relevant text into the question so the links aren't critical in the first place. Sometimes that isn't possible (it's hard to link to a printed book, for example), and if a diagram isn't text you can't copy and paste it as text without horrendous ASCII art), but if it is possible, please edit your question to do so.

Comment: Anyway, the way you're doing things _is_ the way to call a function that expects a `ctypes` array, and the error message you're getting says that the function _doesn't_ expect a `ctypes` array. Maybe there's a bug in the library, or a bug in the docs, or a mismatch where you're using old docs for a new version of the library or vice-versa.

Comment: Thanks for the advices, is the first time I ask something here and I'm a very beginner.

Comment: Thanks for the answer too. In effect when I put something else the error message change. For exemple if I write    SA.St7SetUnits(1, units[0])   returns     expected LP_c_long, got int

Comment: That `LP_c_long` means it wants a pointer to an int, so an int definitely isn’t going to work. An array of ints should automatically “decay” to a pointer to the array the same way it does in C, but if that isn’t working, you can explicitly pass a pointer to the array, maybe by using the `byref` or `pointer` functions from `ctypes`. You shouldn’t have to do this, but if the library writer did something weird in setting up the `argtypes`, maybe that’s the issue, so try it and see what happens.

Comment: One more thing: is that St7API.py file proprietary code that you’re not allowed to share, or can you give us a link to that? (A link to the manual, as mentioned in my first comment, would _also_ be useful if it’s possible.)

Comment: Here there is the complete manual http://www.strand7.com/downloads/Strand7%20R246%20API%20Manual%20TOC.pdf

Comment: I don't know how I can share the file .py.   Maybe this two line for the script can be useful  "St7SetUnits = _ST7API.St7SetUnits"
"St7SetUnits.argtypes = [c_long, ctypes.POINTER(c_long)]". Thank you another time for the help, I will try what you advice above about the ctypes functions as soon as possible.

Comment: That's very strange. If the `argtypes` uses `POINTER(c_long)`, the error shouldn't be saying `expected c_long`. If the error said `expected POINTER(c_long)` it would just be a matter of explicitly decaying the array to a pointer to the first element (as I explained above), but since it's not… I have no idea.

Comment: I upload the St7API.py in dropbox https://www.dropbox.com/s/88plz2funjqy1vb/St7API.py?dl=0. I change the question in relation of what we discuss in this comments. Thank you for having tried to understand the problem.

Comment: Sorry, one more thing: can you write me explicity how can I use the function 'bryef' or 'pointer'? In what point of the script I have to use it? I don't know ctype at all and I don't understand how can I use these functions. It's just for try a last time.

Comment: There's an example in the [`ctypes` docs section "Passing pointers"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#passing-pointers-or-passing-parameters-by-reference). Also read ["Pointers"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#pointers), and [Type conversions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#type-conversions) to understand what it's doing. (Also, you need to know that `LP_c_long` means the same thing as `POINTER(c_long)`.)

Answer (score 0):

I know its been a while, but this works for me:

```
units_type=ctypes.c_long*6
Units = units_type(0,1,3,1,1,2)
St7API.St7SetUnits(1,Units)
```

Answer (score 0):

From your screenshots it looks like you might be using Grasshopper. If so, you might need to explicitly cast the units array to a pointer by adding this line to the top of your script:

```
PI = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_long)
```

And do this whenever you pass an array from IronPython to St7API:

```
SA.St7SetUnits(1, PI(units))
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56370424/11308690) has slightly more.