# IronPython: Message: expected c_double, got c_double_Array_3

Tags: python, ctypes, ironpython

I’m currently developing a script using the python script editor in Rhino. As I’m currently working in a Windows machine, the script editor uses IronPython as language.

In the same script, I want to interact with an FE software (Straus7) which has a Python API. When doing so, I have experienced some problems as the ctypes module does not seem to work in IronPython the same way it does in **regular Python**. Especially, I’m finding problems when initializing arrays using the command:

```
ctypes.c_double*3
```

For example, if I want to obtain the XYZ coordinates of a node #1 in the FE model, I regular Python I would write the following:

```
XYZType = ctypes.c_double*3
XYZ = XYZType()
node_num = 1
st.St7GetNodeXYZ(1,node_num,XYZ)
```

And this returns me a variable XYZ which is a 3D array such that:

```
XYZ -> <straus_userfunctions.c_double_Array_3 at 0xc5787b0>
XYZ[0] = -0.7xxxxx -> (X_coord)
XYZ[1] = -0.8xxxxx -> (Y_coord)
XYZ[2] = -0.9xxxxx -> (Z_coord)
```

On the other side, I copy the same exact script in **IronPython**, the following error message appears

```
Message: expected c_double, got c_double_Array_3
```

Obviously, If I change the variable XYZ to c_double; then it becomes a double variable which contains only a single entry, which corresponds to the first element of the array (in this case, the X-coordinate)

This situation is quite annoying as all FEM softwares, the usage of matrices and arrays is widely used. Consequently, I wanted to ask if anyone nows a simple fix to this situation.

I was thinking of using the memory allocation of the first element of the array to obtain the rest but I’m not so sure how to do so.

Thanks a lot. Gerard

Comment: Apparently *Straus7* **doesn't** have a *Python API*  (since you need to use *ctypes*). It has a *C API*. Didn't work with *IronPython* but what does the `St7GetNodeXYZ` function signature look like (it should be in a *.h* file)? Can you also post the lines whre you initialize `st.St7GetNodeXYZ` and `st`? And are you running the same script with the 2 interpreters?

Comment: Hello, Thank you for the reply. Here below I'm adding the signature: `St7SetNodeXYZ.argtypes = [c_long, c_long, ctypes.POINTER(c_double)]`. To initialize the API is quite simple as I just need to add the module with all API functions to Conda Lib folder and then import it in the python script as `import St7API as st`. Yes, my plan was to use the in-built script editor in Rhino to access Straus7 API. However, this error occurred and thus I started using Spyder with regular Python

Comment: I was asking for the *C* signature, not for the *Python* translation (which was kind of obvious).

Answer (score 0):

I've found when working with IronPython you need to explicitly cast the "Array of three doubles" to a "Pointer to double". So if you're using Grasshopper with the Strand7 / Straus7 API you will need to add an extra bit like this:

```
import St7API
import ctypes

# Make the pointer conversion functions
PI = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_long)
PD = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double)

XYZType = ctypes.c_double*3
XYZ = XYZType()
node_num = 1

# Cast arrays whenever you pass them to St7API from IronPython
St7API.St7GetNodeXYZ(1, node_num, PD(XYZ))
```

I don't have access to IronPython or Strand7 / Straus7 at the moment but from memory that will do it. If that doesn't work for you you can email Strand7 Support - you would typically get feedback on something like this within a day or so.